# General Questions about MySQL and MySQLite

Tags: mysql, windows, perl

I am going to be writing to a MySQLite database file, using Perl's [DBD:SQLite](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD%3a%3aSQLite) module, and I wondering if it is possible for this file to be read by any distribution of MySQL? Is there a better way to create a simple MySQL database (using Perl)?

If it means anything, I'm only going to be using the database to store key-value pairs based on unique ID numbers for the keys. I tried BerkeleyDB but there is little support for it on Perl and I could not get it to work correctly in the past on certain versions of Windows.

Edit: I am aware that BerkeleyDB is a better way to do this, but when I was writing scripts for it, most of the methods have TODO, and I've had mysterious bugs on Windows Server 2003 using the same airtight code that ran for 2 weeks straight on my Win7 machine at home.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no `MySQLite`. There is a `SQLite` and it's fantastic!

Comment: There is quite a bit of support for BerkeleyDB in Perl.  DB_File is the basic way to access it, available with Perl if it was built with BDB support.  There's also the BerkeleyDB module on CPAN which provides access to more of the BDB interface.  http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?BerkeleyDB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Perl's [DBI module](http://dbi.perl.org/) which I can use to read databases using either MySQL or SQLite. All you need is the correct driver. In fact, if you write your program correctly, the backend database (either SQLite or MySql) is irrelevant. Your program will work with either one.

However, you can't use a SQLite database and then treat it as a MySQL database. They're two different creatures. Your program can be database agnostic, but once you chose a database, you can't switch back and forth. It'd be like opening an Oracle database as a MySQL database.

See [This posting on Perl Monks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=619077) for more info.

Answer (score 5):

MySQL and SQLite are completely separate RDBMS systems. There is no such thing as MySQLite. To the best of my knowledge, MySQL cannot read SQLite databases.

If all you really want is a key-value store, perhaps look at Redis: http://code.google.com/p/redis/

Comment: In fact MySQL syntax is quite different (`CREATE`, `ALTER` etc) from SQLite. They're very much not compatible. Most `SELECT` queries are however.

Answer (score 2):

BerkeleyDB is well supported by perl.  You have a choice between the older DB_File and the more fully featured BerkeleyDB module.

But there are tons of choices.  If you don't want to have to run a separate server process, use DBI and DBD::SQLite or BerkeleyDB or any of the AnyDBM_File modules.  For a simple server-based key-value store, there's redis or the older memcached.